# c# How to identify accountId and Region in a AWS Lambda call?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I need to identify the accountId and the region of the AWS account that triggered an AWS Lambda function. I did not find these infos in the ILambdaContext.
How can I have access to these infos?
It's being triggered by an SNS
I'm using .Net Core 2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to identify the account id is to use secure token service (STS). Use the following method
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/SecurityToken/MISecurityTokenServiceGetCallerIdentityGetCallerIdentityRequest.html

IAmazonSecurityTokenService.GetCallerIdentity

Add the Nuget package AWSSDK.SecurityToken , then create sts client

```
IAmazonSecurityTokenService stsClient = new AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient();
string accountId=stsClient.GetCallerIdentityAsync(new GetCallerIdentityRequest()).Result.Account;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to your Lambda Execution Context, then you can extract the AWS Region and AWS Account ID right from the InvokedLambdaFunctionArn within the context object.
When you invoke your Lambda Function, depending on the integration type the handler accepts either an event-object or two arguments - the request object and the execution context.

Answer (score 0):

You can add AccountNumber to Environment variables and read:

```
var accountNumber = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AccountNumber")
```

Comment: Actually I'm considering that more than 1 account can trigger the lambda function, and I Need the accountId who triggered to publish a message on SNS of that account. This way, it should be dinamically